# How to avoid Firefox preventing 'viber://forward?text='?

Tags: firefox, share, viber

I'm trying to put a viber share link on my site, it looks like that:

```
     <a href="viber://forward?text=here_my_url_text">Share me</a>
```

It works on Chrome but neither on Firefox.
I get a message in the console:
Prevented navigation to “viber://forward?text=https://...../” due to an unknown protocol.

How to make it work on Firefox?

Comments:
I've made some checking and found that it works on windows normally(win10x64, Viber of course should be installed). In my case, I use Fedora32 and Firefox seems doesn't see the Viber app and prevents navigation to it.

Comment: The protocol they are talking about is `viber://`